# Change default dict into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have a dictionary (shown below), the values are default dictionaries with the inner value being a list. I am trying to turn this dictionary into another dictionary with the same higher level key and a nested dictionary that contains the same inner key and a sum of "4" values in the list.

For example the expected output for the first entry is, {'google' : {'dog':1,'cat':2}}

```
{'google': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'dog': [4, 0], 'cat': [4, 4, 0]}), 'ibm': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'dog': [4], 'bird': [0]}), 'kaspersky': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), 'amazon': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), 'facebook': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), 'sony': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), 'microsoft': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {}), 'apple': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})}
```

I am using the code below to try to do this but am getting the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str".

```
def swords_neg(dictionary):
    for key,value in dictionary.iteritems():
        company_sent_dict_three[key] = []
        for i,j in dict(value).iteritems():
            for sent in j:
                company_sent_dict_three[key][i] += sent

    print company_sent_dict_three
```

Comment: `and a sum of "4" values in the list.` Did you mean a *count* of such values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following nested [dict comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html):

```
{
    k: {k_: sum(x==4 for x in v_) for k_, v_ in v.items()} 
    for k, v in dictionary.items()
}
# {'google': {'dog': 1, 'cat': 2}, 
#  'ibm': {'dog': 1, 'bird': 0}, 
#  'kaspersky': {}, 
#  'amazon': {}, 
#  'facebook': {}, 
#  'sony': {}, 
#  'microsoft': {}, 
#  'apple': {}}
```

`k, v` are the key-value pairs of the outer `dict`, `k_, v_` are the key-value pairs of each inner `defaultdict`. [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a convenience util to count the occurrences of `4` for each innermost list via `sum(x==4 for x in v_).`

Comment: this currently also shows values that equal "0" in the dictionary ( eg. bird : 0). can it only show the sum of values that equal "4"?

Comment: @dmnte You mean, you want only keys in the inner dicts that actually contain any 4?

Comment: I mean in a case such as, "'ibm': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'dog': [4], 'bird': [0]})" the output records "'ibm': {'dog': 1, 'bird': 0}". This is correct since its value is zero, but is it possible to not even have it added to the dictionary in this instance ? So only adding sum of 4's if there is a 4 present, otherwise not adding it